# What is the position of Lord Vishnu according to Srikanta Shivacharya?

Tags: vishnu, vedanta, shaivism, brahma-sutras, shivadvaita

According to different Shaiva traditions, Lord Vishnu is either a baddha jivatma (transmigratory being) or samashti jivatma (Qualified being), for an example Kashmiri Shaiva Sampradaya gives the position of Vishnu as baddha jivatma along with Brahma and Rudra.

> परमेश्वरेच्छाप्रेरितमायागर्भाधिकारीयरुद्रविष्णुब्रह्मा-दिद्वारेण।
>
> (For those desiring bhoga) descent of grace occurs by MayaGarbhadhikari (Presiding deities of the realm of Maya): Rudra, Vishnu, and Brahma who are impelled by the will of Parameswara.
>
> **(Tantrasara Chapter 11)**

Also it lists Vishnu as one amongst 6 karana devas undergoing different phases in their life.

> बाल्य-यौवन-वार्धक-निधन-पुनर्भव-मुक्त्यधिपतय एते।
>
> They are the superintending deities of childhood, youth, old age, death, rebirth, and liberation.
>
> **(Tantrasara Chapter 4)**

Similarly, in Dashanami Shaiva sampradaya of Adi Shankaracharya, Lord Vishnu is worshipped as samashti jivatma (Excelled/Qualified being) on which you can study about in a detailed format [here.](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://adbhutam.wordpress.com/2017/08/02/vishnu-is-samashti-jiva-shankara-in-mundaka-bhashya/&ved=2ahUKEwiT6-fSpoL_AhWz7TgGHZZqAHUQFnoECBAQAQ&usg=AOvVaw1s6hx6BcsS5LLcvcsTnFSz)

My question is, what about the same in Srouta Shaivism of Srikanta Shivacharya, what is the exact position of lord Vishnu and how is his subservience towards Parameshwara Shiva interpreted or ideologised.